# Difference between .htm and .html in Outlook 365

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, thunderbird

I'm trying to add a custom HTML signature in Outlook 365. Therefore I create a normal signature and go to ...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures to edit the signaturename.htm file.

But even if I'm defining the language (charset utf-8) it seems to use a different language.

And I just can't copy and paste my code from my .html file to the .htm file. Is there a big difference between .html and .htm?

If I use my .html file in Thunderbird everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing different between .htm and .html files, but, the ...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures file is generated from Outlook, and therefore contains all sorts of Microsoft-specific code.

You should create a new email in outlook, and then under 'include' click 'signature' -> signatures, as per below image.

[image: Outlook 365 Signature edit]

Then edit your signature there, copying your HTML into the box below.